# How to save/reload the fake blockchain in Mix

Tags: cpp-ethereum, mix

I'd like to save the state of the fake blockchain and to reload it on Mix startup. Any hints?

Comment: `fake blockchain`? what is that?

Comment: It is the blockchain you can use in Mix to locally test your contracts without actually deploy them on the network. It is part of the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deeper digging in the GUI I found that "Seal Block" button actually saves the state of the blockchain in the scenario.